# Make a UIToolbar above the keyboard with multiple selections

Tags: iphone, xcode, keyboard, uitextview

I have a screen in my app that contains multiple UITextViews. The user needs to be able to switch back and forth between the UITextViews quickly to take notes. I had the idea to create a UIToolbar above the keyboard with 5 buttons, and when one is pressed, it switches to that UITextView, like the Next and Previous buttons in many apps, only more specific. I unfortunately have no code to further illustrate what I'm trying to do, as I have absolutely NO idea where to begin on this. I've never done any custom keyboard controls before.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a `inputAccessoryView`. That way you don't have to worry about the animations etc. Just do:

```
textField.inputAcccessoryView = <your_custom_view>
```

This is what I have for a `inputAccessoryView` in my code:

```
- (UIView *)textFieldAccessoryDoneButton {
    UIView *accessoryView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIButton *accessoryDoneButton = <your_button_here>;
    accessoryDoneButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:Gotham_Bold size:12];
    [accessoryView addSubview:accessoryDoneButton];

    return accessoryView;
}
```

Comment: Could you go into a bit more depth on how the inoutAccessoryView should be implemented? I've never even heard of it. :P